# Subsetting by multiple aggregate conditions in dplyr

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr, indicator, dummy-variable

I was hoping someone knew of an easy/efficient in dplyr in which I can define an indicator variable to take the value of 1 if on Date X, an IP address was present >50 times.  The data is two columns, one of IP addresses and the other associated access dates.

As an example, I would like the following output in the Robot column (assuming that the Date/IP combination was >=3).

```
IP Date Robot
1   A   1
1   A   1
1   A   1
1   B   0
2   B   0
2   C   1
2   C   1
2   C   1
3   C   0
3   D   0
4   A   0
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: @akrun, included above!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `group_by` the two variables and use `n()` to test how many adresses where present that day.

```
group_by(df,date,ip) %>% 
  mutate(keep=as.numeric(n() > 50))
```

Comment: You don't really need `ifesle` here, just `group_by(df, IP, Date) %>% mutate(keep = as.numeric(n() > 2))` should do.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency same logic in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread("IP Date
            1   A   
            1   A   
            1   A   
            1   B   
            2   B   
            2   C   
            2   C   
            2   C   
            3   C   
            3   D   
            4   A")

DT[, Robot := ifelse(.N >= 3, 1, 0), keyby = .(IP, Date)]
```

Of course, you need to change the condition to `.N >= 50` when you want 50 the be the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by "IP", and "Date", we create the "Robot" by converting the logical (`.N>=3`) to binary representation.  This can be done by just using `+` to the logical vector or using the function `as.integer`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Robot:= +(.N>=3), .(IP, Date)]
```

The `+` can be replaced by `as.integer`

---

Or with `base R`, we can use `ave`

```
transform(df1, Robot=as.integer(ave(IP, IP, Date, FUN=length)>=3))
```